# Pass the value from an instance as an argument

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am retrieving the key and trying to pass it in a header while doing GET request, but getting an error.

Utils.js (Here I am retrieving the token)

```
class Utils {
    getKey(){
    let key
    return cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/sign-in',
        body: {
            "password" : "password",
            "email" : "email"
        },
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response)=>{
        expect(response.body).have.property('access_token')
        key = response.body['access_token']        
    })
return key
}
}

export default Utils
```

Then I am trying to pass the token in `headers`

```
import Utils from '../../fixtures/Utils'

describe("HTTP Example", ()=>{
    let utils = new Utils()
    it('GET', ()=>{
        console.log(utils.getKey())
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/users',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': utils.getKey()
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property('name', 'Test user')
            console.log(response)
        })
    })
```

Getting Error: Target cannot be null or undefined.

Comment: What does `console.log(utils.getKey())` show? You might just need to check `if (utils.getKey())` before making your `GET` request.

Comment: What does your response contains? It's easy to debug these kind of errors you just need to console.log everything.

Comment: @jdaz it returns an object instead of string: Message:   expected { Object (access_token) } to have property access_token.
But If I add `return key.access_token` it returns an error: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning value from a method/function in Cypress, then you have to access the value by chaining only. Below is the snippet which solves your problem. Let me know if it worked or not.

```
utils.getKey().then(authToken => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/users',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': authToken
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property('name', 'Test user')
        cy.log(response)
      })
    })
```

Comment: The problem here as I can see from console in Utils class, because getKey returns an object instead of string: Message:   expected { Object (access_token) } to have property access_token. But If I add return key.access_token it returns an error: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined

Comment: I suggest you to put `console.log()` statements and see what exactly the response is. If it returns the object, then try to do `JSON.stringify()` and see what you are missing. You are seeing Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined error as there is nothing returned and you are trying to fetch `access_token` out of it.